# getItem() of ViewPager Fragment called twice

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am doing swiping application in android. But I got one problem that getItem() method
is calling twice initially. I tried to solve this but I didn’t get solution. please help me
to find out solution. below snippets my code:-

public class DisplayEMIBOFQuestionActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
private ViewPager pager;
private  int savePosition;
private Context context;
private String fragTag1;
private String fragTag2;

    /*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.common_emi_bof_display_question);
    context = getLayoutInflater().getContext();     
    if(Helper.isTablet)
    {
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }else
    {
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
    // Initialise the pager
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        public void onPageSelected(int position) {}

        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float arg1, int arg2) {}

        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {


         }

    });     
            getPager().setPageTransformer(true, new SwipeAnimation());

}
public ViewPager getPager() {
    return pager;
}
public void setPager(ViewPager pager) {
    this.pager = pager;
}
public String getFragTag1() {
    return fragTag1;
}
public void setFragTag1(String fragTag1) {
    this.fragTag1 = fragTag1;
}
public String getFragTag2() {
    return fragTag2;
}
public void setFragTag2(String fragTag2) {
    this.fragTag2 = fragTag2;
}



public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        System.out.println("************** "+pos);


        Helper.currentQuestion = pos;
        if(Helper.randomQuestionList.get(pos).getSubQuestionType().equals(QuestionType.BOF.toString()))


        return new DisplayBOFQuestionFragment();
        else 

            return new DisplayEMIQuestionFragment();

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return Helper.NUMBEROFQUESTIONS;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return super.getPageTitle(position);
    }
}

public void setPagerPosition(int pos){      
    pager.setCurrentItem(pos);
}
```

}

Comment: Its the default behaviour..it will load its adjacent pages also..

Comment: then there is any alternate way to solve this problem?

Comment: Actually what is your requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

It gets one fragment and two adjacent ones (here you just have one), so initially will get Tab1 and Tab2 to get ready when you swipe to Tab2, at Tab2 selected will also call getItem for Tab3 to prepare for swipe.